# me sale error al momento de importar csv

Tags: php, mysql, csv

hola estoy haciendo la exportación e importación en php + mysql + csv de una tabla con varios registros algunos 3000 registros otros 10 y con los de 10 registros exporta e importa normal, con los 3000 o 2000 registros exporta normal pero no me importa y me sale el siguiente error porfavor ayudenme amigos este es el error

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\SISINVED\importData.php on line 62
```

este es mi codigo

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconnecta.php';
   if(isset($_POST['importSubmit'])){
$csvMimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain');
if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'],$csvMimes)){
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){


        $csvFile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');



        fgetcsv($csvFile);


        $conexion->query("DELETE FROM  detalleinventarioinicial where idcolegio='$idcod' ");
         while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE){


$conexion->query("INSERT INTO detalleinventarioinicial (idingreso, nro, codigo, descripcion, unidad,cantidad,marca,serie,color,tipo,procedencia,docingreso,numdocingreso,estado,observacion,idcolegio,idusuario,modificacion,bien,patrimonial,ano,idlaboratorio,canti,foto,modelo,dimension) VALUES ('".$line[0]."','".$line[1]."','".$line[2]."','".$line[3]."','".$line[4]."','".$line[5]."','".$line[6]."','".$line[7]."','".$line[8]."','".$line[9]."','".$line[10]."','".$line[11]."','".$line[12]."','".$line[13]."','".$line[14]."','".$line[15]."','".$line[16]."','".$line[17]."','".$line[18]."','".$line[19]."','".$line[20]."','".$line[21]."','".$line[22]."','".$line[23]."','".$line[24]."','".$line[25]."')");
              }

               fclose($csvFile);

            $qstring = '?status=succ';
        }else{
            $qstring = '?status=err';
        }
    }else{
        $qstring = '?status=invalid_file';
    }
}

header("Location: adimportarinventario1.php".$qstring);?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mírate este link. La respuesta habla de que se puede cambiar el default script's timeout setting, que por defecto es 30 segundos.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162176/reading-very-large-files-in-php
No programo en php, pero creo que se refiere a esto:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.set-time-limit.php
Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Me sirvio de mucho excelente tu ayuda  code_learner